# What does the themeapiport do?

Tags: malware

In the report of a malware analysis service I found the followoing concerning an analyzed file:

```
Connects to LPC ports

details: "<Input Sample>" connecting to "\ThemeApiPort"
source: API Call
```

What does this mean? What is the \ThemeApiPort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is the \ThemeApiPort?

`\ThemeApiPort?` is an LPC port used for interprocess communication, in this case to provide theme management on Windows XP.

> LPC  (Local  Procedure  Call)  is  a Microsoft Windows  kernel  component  used  for  communication between  processes (IPC).  This  undocumented  interface  is  used  in the background  of the known Windows  API. Most  system  components  use the LPC  interface  to  communicate  with  lower-level security programs

Source [WINDOWS PRIVILEGE ESCALATION THROUGH LPC AND ALPC INTERFACES](https://recon.cx/2008/a/thomas_garnier/LPC-ALPC-paper.pdf) (pdf).

The above paper identifies privilege escalation vulnerabilities associated with LPC and ALPC interfaces.

> The (A)LPC interface is part of Windows NT's undocumented Native API, and as such is not available to applications for direct use. However, it can be used indirectly in the following instances:
>
> - when using the Microsoft RPC API to communicate locally, i.e. between the processes on the same machine
> - by calling Windows APIs that are implemented with (A)LPC

Source [Local Inter-Process Communication - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Inter-Process_Communication)

There are several viruses that have taken advantage of `\ThemeApiPort` vulnerabilities to inject code into Windows processes, for example:

> TR/Spy.1350396
>
> Injections > `%WINDIR%\System32\svchost.exe{<-\ThemeApiPort}`

Source [TR/Spy.1350396 - Avira Virus Lab](https://www.avira.com/en/support-threats-summary/tid/23747/threat/TR.Spy.1350396)